# A historical computer chess endgame

Tags: engines, endgame

In Season 11 Superfinal Game 78 the following opposite color Bishop endgame was reached:

```
[FEN "8/2p1k3/1p6/p4B2/P2P1bP1/2P5/1P3K2/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

In that Superfinal Stockfish smashed Houdini 20 wins versus 2 , but this endgame is interesting because , if Stockfish ( black) did draw it would have completed the Superfinal with a record of only one loss. I am not certain because the tabulates indicated Stockfish was in time trouble at this juncture of the game. Is the endgame a win or a draw? I ask to look (at least) past depth 48.

Comment: White or black to move in that position? *Please* take a look at how the [replayer](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/179/7297) works, so you can use them on your own.

Comment: It is white to move

Comment: I doubt you'll find an answer by just letting an engine think until depth 48 or higher. You'd need to play this endgame out (moving the pieces in your chess software's board) to analyze a number of different lines with the engine. Even then I don't know if you'll find a definitive answer, but you'll probably gain a good hunch of what the objective result is.

Comment: Why exactly depth 48? In an endgame like this, depth 48 is basically nothing.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't put any effort into this however just letting the engine search, it seems to be winning for White, evaluation steadily rising:

```
[FEN "8/2p1k3/1p6/p4B2/P2P1bP1/2P5/1P3K2/8 w - - 0 1"]

1. Ke2 c5 2. Kd3 cxd4 3. cxd4 Kd6 4. Kc4 Bh6 5. Be4 Bd2 6. Kb5 Kc7 7. Bh1 Be3 8. Kc4 Kd8 9. Bd5 Ke7 10. Bg8 Kd6 11. d5 Ke5 12. Kb5 Kd6 13. Bf7 Kc7 14. b4 axb4 15. Kxb4 Kd6 16. Kc4 Bf4 17. Bg8 Bc1 18. Kb4 Kd7 19. Be6+ Kd6 20. Kb5 Be3 21. Kc4 Bf4 22. Kd4 Bg3 23. Bc8 Ke7 24. Kd3 Bd6 25. Be6 Bh2 26. Kd4 Bf4 27. Ke4 Bg5 28. Kf5 Bd2 29. g5 Bc1 30. Bc8 Kd6 31. Bb7
```

+- (6.25 ++)  Tiefe: 57/53   00:45:26  8834MN, tb=31896574

You can get the current version of Stockfish here https://abrok.eu/stockfish/ , then you can run your own searches.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: The following position came up in a variation of the Two Knight Defense 5k2/B5p1/2p5/8/1bP5/1P6/6KP/8 with Black to move. It is a win or a draw ?

Comment: @Stefano why not just run it yourself? As linked, Stockfish is free, Leela is free as are plenty of other engines. Not much point in posting every single analysis position here...